# Can each alternate page print a specific subreport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to create an INVOICE. In the invoice each even page will contain terms and conditions. If we consider a three pages invoice, actually it will take 6 pages. Page 1,3,5 will contain the invoice data and page 2,4,6 will contain the terms and conditions(same dynamic text in three pages). Is it possible in Jasper Report?

Comment: Use subreports, Detail Bands, and PrintWhenExpressions.